# dhcp ipv6 dynamic prefix delegation

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, ipv6

I'm trying to setup Linux-based home gateway with IPv6 support. IPv4 configuration is finished and I'm using IPv4 NAT, ISC DHCP for addresses allocation, PowerDNS for local DNS setup, PDNS recursor to speedup address resolution.

I'm getting /64 IPv6 dynamic prefix from my ISP and I would like to reuse it and be able to allocate addresses from this subnet for my local network devices. Would be great if host part of the IPv6 address will be static and only subnet part changed.

In short, I need the DHCP server implementation which can allocate addresses from dynamic /64 subnet provided by ISP.

How can I achieve this? I'm unable to find a good explanations/examples of such a config, so asking for the help.

**Edit:** Found interesting resource, describing my problem. Seems the status is the same (since 2012?!): http://www.kloepfer.org/ipv6-homenet.html, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't agree that this is too broad. It's about configuring DHCPv6 PD, which is theoretically simple to do but it's still kind of a new thing so best current practices have not really emerged so I think there's a lack of usable recipes, which makes this actually quite a good question.

Comment: Having said that, and notwithstanding the fact that it is technically possible to subnet in v6 to longer prefix lengths than /64, DHCPv6 PD is not actually going to work properly in this case because the ISP is handing out a /64. There is only one subnet, thus nothing to split up and delegate. The ISP should **not** be handing out a /64, **they should be handing out a /48 per customer** or at the very least a /56 per customer.

Comment: @Celada, thanks for your input, I will take a look at PD... unfortunately there is a problem with **should** and **actually do**. I don't think I can **force** provider to give me a biger subnet.

Comment: You can configure your chosen DHCP client to request a larger prefix. A router-focused Linux distribution like OpenWrt makes this simple.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thanks for the suggestion. Any clue how to do that using ISC dhclient? Am I right, that in such case I will always get the same prefix (kind of static IP)?

Comment: And nothing seems to had changed still. I'm in the same need as yours, and can't find how to setup pihole to grab IPv6 prefix via PD from router.